# Styling MDX Files with Chakra UI

Tags: reactjs, typescript, next.js, eslint, mdxjs

I am trying to style markdown files using Chakra UI in a next.js app.  To that extent, I have created the following `MDXComponents.tsx` file:

```
import { chakra } from "@chakra-ui/react"

const MDXComponents = {
  p: (props) => <chakra.p fontSize="2xl" color="blue.500" {...props} />,
}

export default MDXComponents
```

I then import this file into `_app.tsx` and everything works as I want it to.  Nonetheless, I get the following error in the `MDXComponents.tsx` file: `Component definition is missing display name`:

[image]

Any idea why I am getting this error message and what I can do to fix it?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have an eslint rule enabled that forces you to give your components a displayName, either by giving the function that returns a JSX component a name, or by manually setting a displayName to the component.

As you can see, your functions that return the components are anonymous arrow functions. eg:

```
  p: (props) => <chakra.p fontSize="2xl" color="blue.500" {...props} />,
```

Try using a standard function and giving the function a name, like this:

```
  p: function Paragraph(props) {
     return <chakra.p fontSize="2xl" color="blue.500" {...props} />
   }
```

With MDX it could get tedious to always give the  function a name, and arrow functions are cleaner, so I suggest you turn the eslint option off in your eslintconfig file:

```
"react/display-name": "off"
```